# Using apostrophe + s and "the" - is it incorrect and why?

Tags: grammar

I saw a colleague writing:

> Can you add the new option in the Salesforce’s panel?

English is my second language, but my intuition tells me that using `the` with `'s` in this situation is incorrect and you should use either:

> Can you add the new option *in Salesforce’s panel*?

...or:

> Can you add the new option *in the Salesforce panel*?

Am I right and if yes, *why* am I right? What are the grammatical rules that apply here?

Comment: You are correct.  I'll do a little research and see if I can figure out why

Answer (score -1):

You are correct.  The reason is that you don't use "the" with proper nouns, but you do with common nouns.

**INCORRECT**

> Can you add the new option in the Salesforce’s panel?
> Can you add the new option in customer’s panel?

**CORRECT**

> Can you add the new option in Salesforce’s panel?
> Can you add the new option in the customer’s panel?

https://jakubmarian.com/articles-before-possessive-s/

Comment: NB This is true of names of organisations, but it doesn't apply to titles of individuals - e.g. _All the President's men_, and Kipling's _The Colonel's Lady and Judy O'Grady_.

Comment: One has to consider whether 'the' is addressing the noun phrase or just the attributive or  head noun. And some proper nouns usually have the definite article.  'The BBC News' / 'the ITV News' but 'the BBC's offices' / 'ITV's offices'.

Comment: @KateBunting, president and lady are common nouns, and the exception may arise when common nouns are used as titles. We don't say "the sir's estate" because sir is a title and not a common noun.

Comment: @Peter I know that, of course - but _the President_ and _the Colonel_ act as proper nouns when they identify the individual currently fulfilling that role.

Comment: @KateBunting, my point is that the exception you identified only seems to apply to titles which are capitalised common nouns. Do you have an excaption to this observation?

Comment: @Peter What about  persons whose sobriquet begins with _the_, such as The Artful Dodger, The Great Soprendo, The Mighty Quinn?

Comment: @KateBunting, yes indeed! Thanks. And you have made me think - also Robert the Bruce, and the Albert Einstein (or other famous person).